# ANJI use your own code

Tags: java

I don't think this library is well know enough to have a place on stackoverflow, but I'm posting this anyways.

(ANJI stands for another neat java implementation)

I was doing some searching on how to use your own code, but apparently ANJI is the name of a java programmer to help beginners AND a song.

To rub salt into the wound, sourceforge is down (at least right now)

So, I could only get my hands on the actual download, a cached 'Quick start' file and another cached 'Parameters' Neither actually tell me how to use my own code.

So PLEASE can someone tell me how to use my own code for ANJI.

Comment: It should be noted that sourceforge blocks web.archive.org with robots.txt, exacerbating the situation.

Comment: First, there's another source [here](http://nn.cs.utexas.edu/?anji). Second, it's 11 years old and a research grade neural net package. Why do you think this is something to help beginners?

Comment: Elliott Frisch: I didn't say that the library was for beginners, the person that kept on showing up when I typed in ANJI (who seemed to be for beginners), not the library itself. And I'm saying I got the download. But I can't find how to actually use my own code.